# Dynamic Memory Allocate, how to use pointer correctly when dealing with Structure?

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning about Dynamic Memory Allocate now and it's hard to understand, especially when the lecturer mentioned about DMA and structure using pointer.

First, at the line 1 in my code, i get confused what "&ptr->eno" means. we initiate ptr as a pointer so it means ptr hold the address of the memory we reserved, lets say ptr hold the address 2046, is that "&ptr->eno" means writing value to the address of 2046 it point to?

Second, at the line 2, how i can print out the value, cause "ptr->eno" contains value "2046" than when i print it out, it gonna give me the number 2046, not the value i try to stored in the memory location 2046.

My code was copied from the lecture note, i tried to run it on Visual studio, it crashed after i input the values. I am so new with C, my assumption may looks stupid and painful to understand. if you can't understand my explanation, please tell me how to use pointer with structure, may be i can figure out my mistake. Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct emp
{
    int eno;
    char ename[20];
    float esal;
};
void main()
{
    struct emp* ptr;
    ptr = (struct emp*)malloc(sizeof(struct emp));
    if (ptr=NULL)
    {
        printf("out of memory error");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter the value of employee: \n");
        scanf_s("%d%s%f", &ptr->eno, ptr->ename, &ptr->esal); // line 1
    }
    printf("the name is: %s \t the number: %d \t the salary: %f", ptr->ename, ptr->eno, ptr->esal); //line2
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller my mistake, fixed it

Comment: Just remember that a pointer is just a variable that stores the address of something else as its value. So with `int a=5;` and `int *b = &a;` the pointer `b` just stores the address of `a` as its value. When you dynamically allocate with `malloc, calloc or realloc`, those functions reserve a block of memory of the requested size and return *the address* of the beginning of the block of memory. So you are just storing the address to the block of memory in the pointer variable you assign the return to.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: This is the second (that I have come across) pointer related comment you have made today, and I am fan of these! +1 to it.

Comment: How could it crash *there*?! your code has `ptr = NULL` there, it doesn't even go to the *input* branch.

Comment: @WedaPashi - yes, that just seems to be one of the biggest stumbling blocks new C programmers have with pointers. So I try to drop a comment if it looks like that is what they are struggling with. (which means I end up dropping quite a few `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Absolutely fair and a nice thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also add that the abbreviation DMA usually refers to Direct Memory Access, not Dynamic Memory Allocate, so be aware of that when doing your research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that

```
if (ptr=NULL)
```

was a typo (since the subsequent "it crashed after i input the values" could not have happened), there is a fault here:

```
scanf_s("%d%s%f", &ptr->eno, ptr->ename, &ptr->esal);
```

is missing the required size argument for `%s`

```
scanf_s("%d%s%f", &ptr->eno, ptr->ename, 20, &ptr->esal);
```

or instead of hard coding, perhaps

```
scanf_s("%d%s%f", &ptr->eno, ptr->ename, (unsigned)sizeof ptr->ename, &ptr->esal);
```

Comment: This mades it work as expect, i try to use %19s only but it didn't work, but add sizeof (ptr->ename) , or simply add 20, made it work as expected.

Comment: `%19s` would be the solution with plain `scanf`.

Comment: Note that the cast `(unsigned)` or `(unsigned int)` is needed because the result of `sizeof` may not itself be the correct size for the argument. On some systems `sizeof` may return a value of 8 bytes size, but `scanf_s` is expecting an argument of `int` size.

Comment: hello, i am curious, the size of memory is bytes and suppose to return unsigned int value. Its safe but is it necessary?

Comment: `sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`, not `unsigned int`. On my system they are both 4 bytes, but may not be, which is why the cast should be used. For the same reason when printing a size, you should use `%zu` and not `%u`.

Comment: Thank you, i just did a bit of research about different of size_t and unsigned int. My lecture note considers size_t is similar to unsigned int, that made me confused

Comment: They are similar in that they are both unsigned integers but that is all.

Comment: Thank you for your very kind explanation, i understand much more now

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
if (ptr=NULL)
```

doesn't do what you want. You want the comparison operator `==`, not the assignment operator `=`. This will always set `ptr` to NULL, making the rest of the code have undefined behavior (which often leads to crashes in practice). Enabling, and *looking at*, compiler warnings is a very good way of avoiding this problem.

For the actual question, `&ptr->eno` means "the address of the field `eno` in the struct pointed to by `ptr`". In practice it will evaluate to the value of `ptr`, plus the offset from the start of the structure to the field `eno`, which in this case will be 0 since `eno` is the first field.

Furthermore, the `printf()` should of course be inside the `else`, since you can only run that if `ptr` is not NULL.

And, importantly: you must provide a buffer size for the string to `scanf_s()`.):

> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So, it should be:

```
const int num = scanf_s("%d%s%f", &ptr->eno, ptr->ename, (unsigned int) sizeof ptr->ename, &ptr->esal);
if (num == 3)  // All conversions succeeded, we can rely on them
{
  printf("the name is: %s \t the number: %d \t the salary: %f", ptr->ename, ptr->eno, ptr->esal); //line2
}
```

And you should check its return value, otherwise you risk using non-initialized variables if the input fails for some reason.

Note that the size of the buffer seems to be specified as `unsigned int`, and not `size_t`, which is ... not optimal in my point of view so the cast is needed.

By the way, "DMA" typically means "[direct memory access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)" and has nothing to do with this; that was confusing me for a while.

Comment: BTW, if OP enabled all warnings at compilation time (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) he would have been warned for that wrong `if` test

Comment: hi, i edited it, it still crash after i input values.

Comment: `scanf_s("%d%s%f", &ptr->eno, ptr->ename, &ptr->esal); ` is dubious. See the **Remarks** section of [\[ scanf_s documentation \]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Comment: @sjsam it is not dubious, but wrong, I converted my deleted comment into an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed, I just meant the practice of writing such statements. It is pretty hard to find out the mistake there.

Comment: @sjsam those `_s` functions are really no safer at all. They might be safer in execution, but are just as easy to get wrong when coding.

Comment: Thank you for your very kind explanation, one mistake but it has so many theoretical aspects to concern about.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to cast the output of `malloc` (check [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) ), the simplest way to do it would be

```
struct emp *ptr;
ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof *ptr);
```

Then, `==` is used for equal to logical comparison, so

```
if (NULL == ptr)
/* = changed to ==, also put the value first which will help you easily
* fix accidental omission of the second =
*/
{
    printf("out of memory error");
    exit(1); // Exiting with a non-zero status
}
```

<sup>**Note** This should be taken as a supplement to 
[[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431459/1620779) answer</sup>